# Install `opencv_contrib` on Windows for Python via Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, opencv, anaconda

My computer is running Windows 10, and I have installed `OpenCV 3.2.0` with `Python 2.7`.

I want to use the `opencv_contrib` repository.

Does anyone know how to acheive this via `Anaconda`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try conda installing this OpenCV package from a community channel: https://anaconda.org/jlaura/OpenCV3. It should come with the extra OpenCV modules.

You can also try pip installing opencv-contrib-python into your Anaconda environment (you may want to remove OpenCV first):

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```